# Add spell check into a telerik mvc editor

Tags: telerik-mvc

I want to use the telerik editor in a mvc 3 application I am building. Is it possible to add spell check into the editor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem (in MVC2), and solved it by using [jquery spellchecker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/), I found a asp version [there](http://forums.asp.net/t/1519923.aspx) and adapted it to work in MVC2.

The trick to make it work with Telerik editor is to call spell checker on the "good" jquery object, i.e. if your editor is named "ContentEditor", you need to call spellchecker on `$('#ContentEditor-value')`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

At first I looked to integrate the jquery plug-in. Then looked at some other approaches. Finally I'm settling on letting the browser do it.

On chrome it is built-in already (with an issue)
For I.E. and Firefox the Google toolbar lets you spell check any field.

The issue on chrome is that the MVC3 extensions editor seems to hardcode spellcheck="false" via the javascript in the editor javascript file. Chrome seems to honor this tag. If you modify the js file or add some jquery to change the value to true, spellcheck as you type on Chrome is restored. This tag tells me that one day they are going to have a built-in spell check option; just not today